# cefSharp does not work after publication, how can I solve

Tags: c#, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

the code is working perfectly but after publishing it just doesn't open.
I created a page to test graphics, however as the webbrowser C# does not work, as it starts in IE I tried to use Cefsharp but it is not going either,the error that appears to me is Cefsharp.Core.Runtime.dll, the version I am using of cefsharp is 94.4.11. but the problem is that when I use it by Visual Studio 2022 it works but when I do the compilation and I publish it to generate the executable it doesn't just give an error or it doesn't even open

```
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace cefteste
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            criarcef(panel1,p);
        }

        ChromiumWebBrowser p;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void criarcef(Panel panel, ChromiumWebBrowser chromium)
        {
            /*CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            settings.CachePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/GPMDP";
            settings.WindowlessRenderingEnabled = true;
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-smooth-scrolling", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-overlay-scrollbar", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-npapi", "1");
            CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);*/
            chromium = new ChromiumWebBrowser("C:/Users/Bill/Downloads/index(1).html");
            chromium.LoadingStateChanged += (sender, args) => {
                if (args.IsLoading == false)
                    chromium.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.oncontextmenu = function() { return false; };");
            };
            panel.Controls.Add(chromium);
            chromium.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a valid post. You need to explain what doesn't work, what you expect, what it's doing, etc.

Comment: ready already adjusted

Comment: If you are publishing using click once see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/3613#discussioncomment-842336

Comment: you might have forgotten a dll or something